# asp.net avoid duplicate code in header just to have different page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have the following goal:

I Have a list of top menu links on my website

Home * Links * Quotes * Photos

The only difference is that whenever you are on a particular page, I want that page to just be text (not a href link) and the others to be links (to show that this is the page you are on):

i got this working but it seems very bad way of doing it and i am looking for a better way of doing this:

in my master page, i have the following:

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="TopMenuLinks">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In each individual separate page, i have the following (this is the Family Tree Example):

Family Tree would look like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopMenuLinks" runat="server">
 <a href="http://xxx/albums.aspx">Photos</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;
 <a href="http://xxx/globe.aspx">Travel</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;-                
 Family Tree
 <a href="http://xxx/wiki.aspx"><spanstyle="color:"#000088">Wiki</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-
 <a href="http://xxx/blog.aspx"><span style="color:"#000088">Baby Blog</span></a>
</asp:Content>
```

Photos would look like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopMenuLinks" runat="server">
 Photos &nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;
 <a href="http://xxx/globe.aspx">Travel</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;-                
 <a href="http://xxx/globe.aspx">Family Tree</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;-                
 <a href="http://xxx/wiki.aspx"><spanstyle="color:"#000088">Wiki</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-
 <a href="http://xxx/blog.aspx"><span style="color:"#000088">Baby Blog</span></a>
</asp:Content>
```

So as you can see, in each page i essentially have duplicate code with that particular page not as a link.

Is there any cleaner way of doing this without duplicating a lot of this code on everyone of my pages?

the way i am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same thing using a master page, using ASP:Hyperlink controls.  In the code behind on the master page  I had code to set the NavigateUrl to en empty string if the NavigateUrl matched the location of the child page.

It results in the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UserControl for your common code and add a reference to each page. You could expose a Bool property on the control to either render hyperlinks or plain text and set that property as you need on each page.